# Python 2.7: Error not caught by exception due to "raise"

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, nameerror

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

try:
    df_task = df_task.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
except NameError:
    df_task = df2
raise
```

It produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/cld_intern/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 12, in <module>
    df_task = df_task.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
NameError: name 'df_task' is not defined
```

The except block is supposed to catch the NameError, but somehow the inclusion of "raise" without specifying the exception to raise produces a NameError. Why is it so?

---

This runs perfectly:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

try:
    df_task = df_task.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
except NameError:
    df_task = df2
```

---

This runs as expected too:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

try:
    df_task = df_task.append(df2, ignore_index = True)
except NameError:
    df_task = df2
raise Exception("error message")
```

With the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/cld_intern/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 15, in <module>
    raise Exception("error message")
Exception: error message
```

Comment: this does not look possible. Is this the actual code you are trying? Is there anything else in the `except` block?>

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure the name error is not on `df2`?

Comment: thanks for the questions! updated the code and traceback in full

Answer (score 0):

in python 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'df_task' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'df2' is not defined
```

in python2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
NameError: name 'df2' is not defined
```

Are you sure you are using python 2.7?
Like mentioned in the comment, df2 is not defined i guess.